# How to define a method which is invoked when and only when its class is extended?

Tags: java, constructor

A constructor is invoked everytime new instance is created.

I want a method which is invoked when and only when its class is extended, instead of when its class is instanciated.

How can I do that?

---

Thank you Henrik, that solved my problem.

Comment: You mean at compile time? Can you give an example of why you want this / what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by this question, do you mean you want a method to be called when a subclass is instantiated?

Comment: I'd like to create an online shopping site. I define an abstract class "Goods" and extend it and define classes like "Foods" , "Drinks", and so on.At the same time,  I want to make a "Customer" class which has "search goods" method which receives goods category as parameter and returns list of goods under the category.

Comment: @MasatoNagashima I don't understand why that functionality would require invoking a method when a class is extended. Can you post a minimal working example of what you want / what you have that doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry,  I entered before finishing typing. I might forget to renew a list of subclasses when I  add new subclass of "Goods". It would be convinient if there is a way to automatically add class name to the list when I extends "Goods" class like constructor automatically sets up instance's status.

Comment: @MasatoNagashima you should put that in the question, then.

Comment: @Erik @J Smith Sorry I should have. Then it was a lot easier for you guys to answer.

Comment: Yes, I did that but this site somehow says publicly displayed score doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to use the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to locate the derived classes:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("base.package");    
Set<Class<? extends Goods>> goodsTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Goods.class);
```

`goodsTypes` is then a list of all classes that extend your `Goods` class.